# Maintain yml translation files

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization

We are developing a multi-lingual website with 5 diferrent languages at the moment. It is in symfony2 and we are using yml translation files for i18n. Although it works okay for us, sometimes maintaining these files can be a huge pain in the ass. And we are expending to another 3 languages this months, so in a short time it would be trouble to update all files every time we add something to the translation file.

Let me show you an example. I have the `messages.en.yml` file which contains this:

```
index:
    header: Some text in the header
```

Then, we need to add or remove something from this default translation file. This time I add a new row.

```
index:
    header: Some text in the header
    details: And some details, I've just added
```

And I have to do it with other 5 language files searching the rows where they fit.
Of course it is very simple example, but I hope it shows the problem. Our language file is over a thousand line long and there is 5 of them. When I'm developing it is really annoying to add the same row to 5 different files and then give it to the translators.

We did try comparing the default file with some version control system, but it was still really time-consuming to compare for 5 different languages.

All in all my question is that is their a best practice for maintaining multiple translation files at the same time.

Thank you in advance,

Adam

Comment: silly obvious but you use the `translation:update` command line symfony2 tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `translation:update` command for this which updates all translations with the messages found in the twig files. However, it's currently only implemented for the twig usage of the translation component.

You can use the JMSTranslatorBundle to extract from all other translation usages provided by Symfony too. See http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSTranslationBundle/master/usage

Comment: I've known translation:update for a while, but never actually used it well. This command kindof messes up my nice structure of the files because it dumps out every row in "index.header.details" format unindented. It's not nice to give that to a translator in that form.

I was kinda hoping there is an app, or software which dumps the translations in a more presentable form, which I can give to the translators. The problem is, the translators do not really like unformatted yml files... :)

Thanks for the answers though.